# How can i transpose my json data horizontally using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am looking to transpose my json data horizontally using ruby. My json data looks like this

```
[
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type1",
    "Week": "W1",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type1",
    "Week": "W2",
    "Count": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type2",
    "Week": "W1",
    "Count": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type2",
    "Week": "W2",
    "Count": 3
  },
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type3",
    "Week": "W1",
    "Count": 3
  },
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type3",
    "Week": "W2",
    "Count": 4
  }
]
```

and my expected result is like this

```
[
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type1",
    "W1": 1,
    "W2": 2
  },
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type2",
    "W1": 2,
    "W2": 3
  },
  {
    "ID": "ID001",
    "Type": "Type3",
    "W1": 3,
    "W2": 4
  }
]
```

Please let me know how we can do this with Ruby. This is more of a case of merging a value into key by reference the key Type as group by. Like we do in sql queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizing for readability in a functional chaining non-mutation style:

```rb
hashes = [
  { ID: "ID001", Type: "Type1", Week: "W1", Count: 1 },
  { ID: "ID001", Type: "Type1", Week: "W2", Count: 2 },
  { ID: "ID001", Type: "Type2", Week: "W1", Count: 2 },
  { ID: "ID001", Type: "Type2", Week: "W2", Count: 3 },
  { ID: "ID001", Type: "Type3", Week: "W1", Count: 3 },
  { ID: "ID001", Type: "Type3", Week: "W2", Count: 4 }
]

grouped = hashes.group_by do |hash|
  hash.slice(:ID, :Type)
end

values_transposed = grouped.transform_values do |grp|
  grp.map { |h| [h[:Week].to_sym, h[:Count]] }.to_h
end

values_transposed.map { |grp, values| grp.merge(values) }
# => [
#  {:ID => "ID001", :Type => "Type1", :W1 => 1, :W2 => 2},
#  {:ID => "ID001", :Type => "Type2", :W1 => 2, :W2 => 3},
#  {:ID => "ID001", :Type => "Type3", :W1 => 3, :W2 => 4}]
```

Comment: this looks good and perfect. But i need on top of json data and not hashes. i tried with hashes=JSON.parse(json) and commenting your hashes variable, i got this error "undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError

Comment: If you're starting with a JSON _String_ then you'll need it in the same hash format I've used (which is what you pasted in your question), to use my code without any modifications. For one thing, `JSON.parse` by default creates String keys, but you can do `JSON.parse(json_string, symbolize_names: true)` to get Symbol keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [
  {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :Week=>"W1", :Count=>1},
  {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :Week=>"W2", :Count=>2},
  {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type2", :Week=>"W1", :Count=>2},
  {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type2", :Week=>"W2", :Count=>3},
  {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type3", :Week=>"W1", :Count=>3},
  {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type3", :Week=>"W2", :Count=>4}] 
]
```

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  key = g[:Type]
  (h[key] ||= {}).update(ID: g[:ID], Type: key, g[:Week].to_sym=>g[:Count])
end.values
  #=> [{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1, :W2=>2},
  #    {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type2", :W1=>2, :W2=>3},
  #    {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type3", :W1=>3, :W2=>4}]
```

See [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`).

---

The steps are as follows.

```
enum = arr.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:ID=>"ID001",..., :Count=>2}, {:ID=>"ID001",...,
  #     :Count=>2},...,{:ID=>"ID001",..., :Count=>4}]:
  #        each_with_object({})>
```

The first element is generated by `enum` and passed to the block, causing the block variables to be assigned values using [Array Decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :Week=>"W1", :Count=>1}, {}]
g #=> {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :Week=>"W1", :Count=>1}
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is then performed.

```
key = g[:Type]
  #=> "Type1" 

h[key] ||= {}
h["Type1"] = h["Type1"] || {}
h["Type1"] = nil || {}
h["Type1"] = {}

h #=> { "Type1"=>{} }

h[key].update(ID: g[:ID], Type: key, g[:Week].to_sym=>g[:Count])
h["Type1"].update(ID: "ID001", Type: "Type1", "W1".to_sym=>1)
{}.update(ID: "ID001", Type: "Type1", :W1=>1)
  #=> {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1} 
h #=> {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1}
```

The next element is then generated by `enum` and passed to the block.

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :Week=>"W2", :Count=>2},
  #    {"Type1"=>{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1}} 
g #=> {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :Week=>"W2", :Count=>2} 
h #=> {"Type1"=>{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1} 

key = g[:Type]
  #=> "Type1" 
h[key] ||= {}
h["Type1"] = h["Type1"] || {}
h["Type1"] = {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1} || {}
h["Type1"] = {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1}
h #=> {"Type1"=>{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1}} (no change)

h[key].update(ID: g[:ID], Type: key, g[:Week]=>g[:Count])
h["Typt1"].update(ID: g[:ID], Type: key, g[:Week].to_sym=>g[:Count])
{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", "W1"=>1}}.update(ID: g[:ID], Type: key,
  g[:Week].to_sym=>g[:Count])
  #=> {:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1, :W2=>2} 
h #=> {"Type1"=>{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1, :W2=>2}}
```

The calculations are similar for each of the four remaining elements to be generated by `enum` and passed to the block, after which `enum` returns the hash:

```
{"Type1"=>{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type1", :W1=>1, :W2=>2},
 "Type2"=>{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type2", :W1=>2, :W2=>3},
 "Type3"=>{:ID=>"ID001", :Type=>"Type3", :W1=>3, :W2=>4}}
```

The final step is to extract the values from this hash with [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values).

Comment: Beat me to the punch on a similar answer. FWIW, a simple benchmark test indicates this is a fair bit more efficient than the ``group_by`` method.

Comment: @rmlockerd, as you probably noticed, the reason this is relatively efficient is that at each step a new key-value pair is being added to a hash that is the value of key `k` of `h`; that hash (`h[k]`) is not otherwise modified. `group_by` and other uses of hashes would quite similar in performance if, for example, the desired return value were an array containing hashes such as `{:ID=>"ID001", Type=>"Type1", w=>{"W1"=>1, "W2"=>2}}`. In that case the hash `h[k]` would have to be modified--not just added to--at each step.